# "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" error while sorting in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

Here is the view code:

```
@helper sortLink(string name, int id)
{
<a href="@Url.Action("Products", "Home", new { sortBy = id, isasc = (id ==     ViewBag.sortBy ? !@ViewBag.isAsc : @ViewBag.isAsc).ToString().ToLower() })">@name</a> 
}

<h2 class="center">Products</h2>

<table class="Products">
@* header *@

<tr>
<th>@sortLink("ID",1)</th>
<th>@sortLink("Name",2)</th>
<th>@sortLink("Number", 3)</th>
<th>@sortLink("Color", 4)</th>
<th>@sortLink("Standard Cost", 5)</th>
<th>@sortLink("List Price", 6)</th>
<th>@sortLink("Size", 7)</th>
<th>@sortLink("Weight", 8)</th>
</tr>
```

This is the controller code :

```
  {
    AdventureWorksLT2008R2Entities db = new AdventureWorksLT2008R2Entities();
    const int pageSize = 10;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Products(int page = 1, int sortBy = 1, bool isAsc = true)
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> products;

        #region sorting
        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case 1:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID);
                break;

            case 2:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Name);
                break;

            case 3:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductNumber) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductNumber);
                break;

            case 4:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Color) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Color);
                break;

            case 5:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.StandardCost) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.StandardCost);
                break;

            case 6:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ListPrice) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ListPrice);
                break;

            case 7:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Size) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Size);
                break;

            case 8:
                products = isAsc ? db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Weight) : db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Weight);
                break;
        }
        #endregion

        products = db.Products
            .OrderBy(p=>p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();

        ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
        ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;
        ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.Products.Count()/pageSize);

        return View(products);
```

I am following a tutorial and struck on the sorting part where it keeps showing this error,
i need your help to get remove the error and please explain whats going on the Sortlink helper method, i wan't able to understand it well. The person who wrote this tutorial didn't explain much on this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that you're trying to use `ViewBag.isAsc` in the view, but never assigned it.  Also, after the case statement, you're resetting the `products` variable, which completely invalidates the ordering you set up in the case statement-- remove that.  So after it should look like this:

```
switch(sortBy) {
    // include all the case statements here as you have them

    // you need to add a default section to make it a valid switch statement
    default:
    break;
}
#endregion

// (remove the products = statement that was here, it's not needed

ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;
ViewBag.TotalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)db.Products.Count()/pageSize);

// add these two lines, as required by the View
ViewBag.isAsc = isAsc;
ViewBag.sortBy = sortBy;


return View(products
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList()
);
```

Comment: @Mike ok, it looks like you also need to set `ViewBag.sortBy`

Comment: @Mike actually, the real problem is the line after your *case* statement -- you're setting the `products` array again, which messes up the sorting.  See my updated answer.